# Issue with OffsetDateTime deserialization from json request body Spring-Boot REST API

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, json-deserialization, offsetdatetime

I'm having a `OffsetDateTime` field in my *POJO*:

```
@NotBlank(message = "startTime cannot be null or empty; ")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
@JsonSerialize(using = OffsetDateTimeSerializer.class)
private OffsetDateTime startTime;
```

When I try to give the request body for the API with this `offsetTime` JSON field, it shows deserialization error:
: Resolved

```
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` 
from String "2020-07-21T12:12:23.000+0200": 
Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) 
Text '2020-07-21T12:12:23.000+0200' could not be parsed at index 23;
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: 
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` 
from String "2020-07-21T12:12:23.000+0200": 
Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) 
Text '2020-07-21T12:12:23.000+0200' could not be parsed at index 23
```

Is my input correct and how to deserialize this field from JSON?

Comment: What is your JSON looks like?

Comment: {
  "description": "des1",
  "duration": 45,
  "startTime": "2022-02-02T10:23:46.000+0200",
  "type": "CIRCUIT_TRAINING",
  "userId": 1
}

Comment: For offset `+0200` without colon, did you try `XX` instead of `XXX`?  At least that is what you would need in a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I've tried it. There is no problem with your specification! deserialize is working in my case.

Comment: @Mehdi did you try the same input as like i gave in the json?